# How to get just one result out of Js for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm programming a little JS Zombie game with p5 lib. It should count hits when you click on a Zombie and misses when you miss one. But when there are like 10 Zombies in the Array it gives out 10 results per click. It seems simple, but I'm messing around with that problem for to long now. I need a proper solution before I mess up the game with bulky code. THX for help

```js
// object storing arrays

let zom = [];
let hb = 25;

// player info and ui
;
let hits = 0;
let missed = 0;


function setup() {
  let cnv = createCanvas(600, 300, P2D);



  let pos = createVector((width / 2), (height / 2));
  // zombie spawnpoints
  let zp0 = createVector(height / 4 + 35, height / 3);
  let zp1 = createVector(width - 35, height / 2);


  zom.push(new Zombie(zp0));
  zom.push(new Zombie(zp1));


}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  fill(0);
  text("hits: " + hits, 10, 10);
  text("missed: " + missed, 10, 20);
 

  for (let i = 0; i < zom.length; i++) {
    zom[i].move();
    zom[i].show();
  }

}

function Zombie(pos) {

  this.pos = pos;

  Zombie.prototype.move = function() {
    this.pos.x += 0.2;
    if (this.pos.x > width + hb) {
      this.pos.x = -hb

    }
  }
  Zombie.prototype.show = function() {

    circle(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, hb);

  }

}

function mouseClicked() {
  hitBox();
}

function hitBox() {
  let mx = mouseX;
  let my = mouseY;
  for (let i = 0; i < zom.length; i++) {

    if (mx > zom[i].pos.x - hb &&
      mx < zom[i].pos.x + hb &&
      my > zom[i].pos.y - hb &&
      my < zom[i].pos.y + hb) {


      hits += 1;

    } else {

      missed += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>

  <body>

    <script src="main.js"></script>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that you interate over all zombies on a click and set for EVERY one +1 miss or +1 hit.

You should have one method that returns if it is a hit or a miss and than count +1 miss or +1 hit.

Here a pseudo example:

```
mouseclick...{
if(isHit()){
 hits+= 1
 }else{
 missed+=1
}
```

}

```
function isHit(){
 let mx = mouseX;
 let my = mouseY;
 for (let i = 0; i < zom.length; i++) {

    if (mx > zom[i].pos.x - hb &&
      mx < zom[i].pos.x + hb &&
      my > zom[i].pos.y - hb &&
      my < zom[i].pos.y + hb) {
  return true
} 
}
return false
}
```

Comment: If there is a hit on the third zombie, this will return `false` because there is a miss on the _first_ zombie.

Comment: the return false is not in the loop, it returns only false when there is no hit in the loop. If there is a hit, the method will return true directly.

Comment: ah, I see ... I think I missed it because the bracing+indenting is inconsistent. (on my team I'd make you fix that before approving your commit)

Comment: yeah you are right! Sorry for confusing... was hand written in the stackoverflow editor :)

Comment: @ pL4Gu33. I already tried that. It returns a single result but works only on the last Zombie in the Array. all the others are missed either. I have to iterate over all.

Comment: the other problem is that the game has to know which zombie is hitten. Because the particular Zombie needs to get removed when dead and the particles need to be placed at Zombie.pos

Comment: in my example the method still iterate over all. When you hit one, on the first hit, you get a true back and the loop is interrupted. When there is no hit, you get back a false. To the second question... you can return the i/-1 or the zombie itself/undefined if you want instead of a true or false than you have the concrete zombie. There are many possibilities.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 you are certainly right. maybe I implemented it wrong. It's time for me to get some distraction ;) @ Stephen P your example works, but the increment of missed must be after, not in the loop, to increment only one time. Till I implemented it in the game I will certainly have more issues, but I hope I get done before bothering you again. Untill then I will leave this thread open. Thanks to all of you already.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is increment `hits` if there is a hit on *any* zombie, or increment `missed` if there were misses on *all* zombies. You can do that by looping over all zombies and counting a hit as soon as any zombie is hit, or counting a miss if you finish the whole loop and there were no hits

```
function hitBox() {
  const mx = mouseX;
  const my = mouseY;
  for (let i = 0; i < zom.length; i++) {

    if (mx > zom[i].pos.x - hb &&
        mx < zom[i].pos.x + hb &&
        my > zom[i].pos.y - hb &&
        my < zom[i].pos.y + hb)
    {
      // Count the hit and return from the function if this zombie was hit
      hits += 1;
      return;
    }

    // We'll only reach this line if the loop completed
    // without counting a hit and returning.
    // In that case, this was a miss.
    missed += 1;
  }
}
```

This *does* assume that it's only possible to hit one zombie at a time (two zombies can't occupy the same space)

Comment: The `missed +=1` is still in the loop. Put it one line down and it will work, too ;)